# Do Microsoft and Google calendars automatically handle time zone related complications, so that I can use their API data as source of truth?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, microsoft-graph-api, google-calendar-api

I'm building a scheduling type of app that depends on user's Microsoft or Google calendars.

Essentially, my app treats the event times returned by Microsoft/Google calendar APIs as the reference points.

"30 minutes before an event" means the UTC time of 30 minutes before the UTC time of that event as returned by the calendar API, as long as that data is the latest version, no matter how the user's locale/device time zone may have changed.

I have taken a few date time related courses, and understand how extremely complicated it can be to properly manage them.

But because my app does not maintain its own calendar, instead it utilizes the Microsoft/Google calendar data, can I assume that whatever data I obtain is always correct *as of that point in time*?

So if a time zone change occurs due to government/political factors, I will rely on Microsoft/Google to update the user's calendar times, including re-calculation of any future/recurring events. I simply make sure I keep my data synchronized with the calendar API (via change notification APIs and/or periodic polling).

Your advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's the good thing about UTC.. It doesn't have any of this ancillary wrangling, it's just a moment in time.. But people don't really think in it because they don't live in it, and as a result its technical perfection actually ends up being wrong. Jon Skeet wrote some more on it, and it'd be worth reading for you I think - https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/

Comment: Hi.  Could you please give a specific API you're using and the code you're using with that API?  At minimum, point at the doc for that API and let us know which object and field you are talking about.  An example would be helpful as well.  It's very difficult to answer in generalities.

Comment: I can answer the question in your title as simply, "Yes."  But I don't believe that is the extent of what you are looking for.

Comment: I agree with @MattJohnson-Pint above, as i use Microsoft Calendar using Microsoft Graph, i can say it's YES. It provides the notifications/subscriptions/deltas as well to track.